# 301 redirect urls

Tags: linux, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to redirect an old url to a new one using 301

I need an example of RewriteQueryString for the following 301? http://www .example.com/search/?depId=1&typeCatId=1 to the following http://www.example.com/mens/clothing

So when I type in the long URL in the browser, I am redirected to the new, shorter URL

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/\?depId=1&typeCatId=1$ /mens/clothing [R=301]
```

^ Try that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) either in your .htaccess file or the apache configuration.  You might take a look at the RewriteMap feature if you are going to have a lot of different departments, etc. to map.  Using the [R] flag after the RewriteRule will cause the browser to redirect instead of just being an internal redirect.  Using [R=301] will make it a 301 redirect.